# Java Method Using arraycopy Not Working

Tags: java, sorting, arrays

I have the following code:

```
public void add (int value)
{
    if (numElements == list.length)
        System.out.println("Can't add, list is full");
    else
    {
        int hold=0;

        for (int j = 0; j < numElements; j++)   
        {
            int temp = list[j];
            if (temp <= value)
            {
                hold = j;  
            }
        }

        System.arraycopy(list,hold, list, hold+1 ,numElements-hold);
        list[hold] = value;
        for (int i = 0; i< list.length; i++)
            System.out.print(list[i] + ", ");
        System.out.println();

        numElements++;
    }
}
```

The purpose is to put an integer in an array at the correct spot smallest to largest(insertion sort).

When I run the following test code:

```
myList.add(100);
myList.add(50);
myList.add(200);
myList.add(25);
```

The resulting array is: `[25,50,200,100]`

When I debug it after each time the method is invoked the arrays are:

[100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[50, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[50, 200, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[25, 50, 200, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

As you can see the error is happening when the 200 is trying to be put in.

I need some help fixing this...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `arraycopy()` call is fine. The problem is that if the correct insertion point is after all elements in the list, your loop will not determine this.

You might try something like:

```
for(hold = 0; hold < numElements; ++hold) {
   if(list[hold] > value) break;
}
```